# Restricting movement of a 2d object to backward only in UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector

I'm making a simple project in Unity where there is a Ball attached to a `SpringJoint2d component` the ball is on an angled slope, like in the image below:[image]

I simply want the user to be able to drag the ball backward along the edge of the slope only,in other words I don't want the user to be able to move the ball away from the slope or into it.

I'v been trying several ways I thought could do the job hers the script of the dragging with what I tried:
(This Is the updated version)

```
public class ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Transform spring;

    public Transform calcpoint;
    private Vector3 start;
    private Vector3 end;
    private bool isPressed = false;
    RaycastHit2D[] hits = new RaycastHit2D[2];
    RaycastHit2D[] hits2 = new RaycastHit2D[2];
    float factor = 0;
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (!isPressed)
        {
            isPressed = true;
            rb.isKinematic = true;
        }

    }
    private void OnMouseUp()
    {

        isPressed = false;
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        StartCoroutine(release());
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// release the ball from the spring joint after a small amount of time
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IEnumerator release()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        rb.GetComponent<SpringJoint2D>().enabled = false;

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (isPressed)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(spring.position, rb.position) > 3f || spring.position.x < (rb.position.x - 1)) return;//restrict the dragging of the ball to not go beyond the spring point and not too far back
            float angle = 0;
            if (checkGround() > 1)//if we hit the slope with the ray cast downward from the mouse/Tap position
            {

                angle = Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Atan2(hits[1].normal.x, hits[1].normal.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg); //get angle
                factor = (float)(((45 - angle) * 0.02) + 1) * (angle / 45);//an inaccurate formula to offset the ball to be on top of the slope that works just fine with some glitches
                rb.position = hits[1].point + new Vector2(0, factor * 1f);//position the ball at the point were the ray cast downward from the mouse hit 
                                                                         //(that puts the ball center on the line of the slope) so I offset it usinf the formula above

            }
        }
    }
    private int checkGround()
    {
        int h = Physics2D.RaycastNonAlloc(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), -Vector2.up, hits); //cast downwards
        return h;
    }

}
```

here are the settings on the ball:

[image]

and the slope setup:

[image]

The dragging of the ball works fine ,at one point the player could drag it in the air or into the slope, I managed to fix that with the new code so now the player could only drag it on the edge, though my calculations are still a bit flawed and when the slopes angle is changed the ball would dip a bit inside the slope and that causes some problems at release.

The method used to try to solve the problem is simple, when the player start dragging the ball I cast a ray from the mouse downward and pit the ball on the point of impact with the slope ,offsetting it to sit on top of it,right ow the problem is that the offsetting part is not accurate enough.

I hope I explained myself a bit better this time Thanks:)

Comment: Could you post an Image with the components attached to the ball and slope? What is happening now when you pull the ball in a different direction? Does it move at all, maybe it goes trough the slope itself?

Comment: Updated the question with more information and my current progress.

Comment: Have you tried setting the **Rigidbody interpolation mode** to extrapolate? Also if the problem is only occurring when the ball is being moved very fast, you should change the **Collision detection mode** to **continuous dynamic**

Comment: The **Continuous Collision detection** did improve the behavior of the ball on the slope **after release** quiet dramatically it is prefect now so That is a great improvement I never thought of that ,however neither options prevented the ball from dipping i the slope slightly while dragging it.

Comment: If its not much work you could make a short video or a gif explaining the problem you are having.

Comment: unfortunately  I can't reveal more of the project ,but your suggestion did solve the most serious issue, I can try to explain a bit more , when you drag the ball in the current setting it will try to place the ball on the slope by casting a ray down from the position of the mouse to the surface of the slope and put the ball on the point of impact. however this will put the center of the ball on the slope edge,which puts half of the ball inside the slope,the function I use right now to offset the ball upward is not perfect and in some angles it still appears a bit inside the edge of the slope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error I did manage to come up with a perfect solution to the problem so I thought I might as well share the answer maybe it will help someone.

here is the updated code I changed my method of restricting the movement completely now I use simple linear line equation as shown below:

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (!isPressed)
    {
        //cast a ray on the slope 
        if (checkGround() > 1)
        { 
            angle = Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Atan2(hits[1].normal.x, hits[1].normal.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg); //get angle
            slope = Mathf.Tan(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);//get the slope steepiness
        }
        isPressed = true;
        rb.isKinematic = true;
    }

}
private void OnMouseUp()
{

        isPressed = false;
    rb.isKinematic = false;

    StartCoroutine(release());
}
void Update() {

    if (isPressed)
    {
        xMove = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x - spring.position.x;//get how much the mouse moved backward or forward
        if (xMove < -3f ) xMove = -3f; //restrict the drag range to 3 backward
        if (xMove > 0.3f) xMove = 0.3f;//restrict the drag range to 0.3 forward
        xpos = spring.position.x+xMove;//since the ball and the spring start at exactly the same position the new ball's x position would be the spring  x  + the x movement we calculated above
        ypos = (xMove * slope)- spring.position.y; //the y posistion would be y=mx+b so the the x movement * the slop steepiness  - the starting y position
        rb.position = new Vector2(xpos, -ypos);//set the new position of the ball

    }
}
private int checkGround()
{
    int h = Physics2D.RaycastNonAlloc(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), -Vector2.up, hits); //cast downwards
    return h;
}
```